# How to detect a scroll / wheel event only once in a certain period of time?

Tags: javascript, events, scroll, mousewheel

Let's say I have a scroll/wheel event like this:

```
container.addEventListener("wheel", (e) => {
  const isScrollingDown = Math.sign(e.wheelDeltaY);

  // call some function once, don't listen for wheel event anymore
  // then listen for event again when done
}
```

Based on deltaY, I detect whether a user is scrolling down, or up. How would I call a function only once when I detect this (which is immediatly), remove the event listener, and then listen for it again when my function is complete?

I can't remove the event listener from inside my event listener right?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can define loading variable and check each time before run function

```
var loading = false
container.addEventListener("wheel", (e) => {
  const isScrollingDown = Math.sign(e.wheelDeltaY);

  if(!loading){
      loading = true;
     // call some function once, don't listen for wheel event anymore
     // then listen for event again when done
     // after done
     loading = false
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, such a simple implementation, I guess I was thinking too complicated. Will try this, and if it works I'll mark it as the correct answer, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `removeEventListener()` function. [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)

example:

```
let wheelHandler = function(e) {
    toggleListener(wheelHandler, false)
    const isScrollingDown = Math.sign(e.wheelDeltaY);
    // call some function once, don't listen for wheel event anymore
    // then listen for event again when done
    toggleListener(wheelHandler, true)
};
let toggleListener = function(listener, add) {
    if (add) {
        container.addEventListener("wheel", wheelHandler)
    } else {
        container.removeEventListener("wheel", wheelHandler)
    }
}
toggleListener(wheelHandler, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

wait 1 second after first wheel:

```js
    function handleWheel(e){
          console.log(Math.random())
          document.getElementById("container").removeEventListener("wheel", handleWheel)

          setTimeout(()=>{
            document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("wheel", handleWheel);
          },1000); // return event after 1 second
    }

    
    document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("wheel", handleWheel)
```

```html
<div id="container" >wheel</div>
```

Comment: I don't really fancy using setTimeout for stuff like this, considering I'm working with animations..

Comment: "once in a certain period of time?" you asked this

Comment: Yes, a certain period of time being the time after my function has been completed. So this is partly a bad description, my fault, and your answer is correct for that part, but if you read my problem better, you'll see that above implementations are actually cleaner.